# Windows 10 ssh login for active directory users

Tags: windows-10, ssh, active-directory, openssh

I tried to setup an sshd using the addon feature of windows 10 as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse). I did do the *Initial Configuration of SSH Server* as required. However when I tried to connect over ssh like this:

```
ssh mycompany.com\name.surname@20.1.20.1
```

I was promted to enter the password (I entered the domain accounts password). But the terminal returned

```
Permission denied, please try again
```

Maybe this is linked to permission?

I added the following lines to C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config:

```
AllowUsers *
```

And restarted with `Restart-Service sshd` but still the same. I tried to login with ssh from another  machine using git-bash and power-shell. I have installed OpenSSH-Client on this other machine.

On the server side I did try running in C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH:

```
sshd.exe -d
```

Which then did yield the following:

```
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
Connection from 20.1.20.2 port 54915 on 20.1.20.1 port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user name.surname@mycompany.com service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: user n matched group list administrators at line 84
debug1: userauth-request for user name.surname@mycompany.com service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
debug1: auth2_challenge: user=name.surname@mycompany.com devs= [preauth]
debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user name.surname@mycompany.com service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
lookup_principal_name: User principal name lookup failed for user 'corp\\mystrangename1' (explicit: 1355, implicit: 1355)
Accepted password for name.surname@mycompany.com from 20.1.20.2 port 54915 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: name.surname@mycompany.com has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: Not running as SYSTEM: skipping loading user profile
CreateProcessAsUserW failed error:1314
fork of unprivileged child failed
debug1: do_cleanup
PS C:\Windows\system32\OpenSSH>
```

My sshd_config is:

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
       
AllowUsers *
```

Is there something special required to make it work with active directory user accounts?

Comment: If you want help you will need to provide your sshd_config otherwise we cannot help you

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the ssh client and configuration, one of these options should work.

**Option 1**

One of the options is to escape the backslash `\\`:

```
ssh mycompany.com\\name.surname@20.1.20.1
```

**Option 2**

The other method is to use the `-l` login name parameter:

```
ssh -l name.surname@mycompany.com 20.1.20.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with following *workaround* while I did not find a solution for active directory users:

**Short version**

Create local account such as `localusername` with strong password
and connect using that account:

```
ssh localusername@20.1.20.1
```

**Detailed version**

Create new local account (I do it old school way):

1. run `Computer Managemet` as administrator
2. navigate to `Local Users and Groups` > `Users`
3. Right click > New user...

   - Set the username `localusername` always better without spaces
   - Set very strong password
   - [x] Password never expires
   - [Create], [Close]

Connect via SSH using that account, ie `ssh localusername@20.1.20.1`

Comment: I couldn't find a real solution to this problem either so I also reverted to this workaround. I got it to work fine, but only *after* I had changed the new local account to administrator: `Settings` - `Accounts` - `Other users` - select the account - `Change account type`.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that there's no need to explicitly log in or log out of any account locally. You can just stay logged in locally with the Active Directory account and log in to the local account via SSH at the same time.